# Arabic in Qt with QString

Tags: c++, qt, arabic

I want to add an Arabic title to my Qt application, but it didn't work.
Here is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    mainWindow w;
    QString appTitle("تجربه");
    w.setWindowTitle(appTitle);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

How can I correct it?

Comment: And on what OS you code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>That looks like a typical "UTF-8 interpreted as ISO-8859-1" encoding issue.</strike> In fact it's a "CP1256 interpreted as Latin1" issue.

On Windows, with a non-Unicode codepage, try the following:

```
QString appTitle = QString::fromLocal8Bit("تجربه");
```

If you had your source file in UTF-8, try this instead:

```
QString appTitle = QString::fromUtf8("تجربه");
```

(See [`codecForLocale()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html#codecForLocale) for what that's supposed to do.)

Qt Creator 2.7/Windows 7 (in a VM)/UTF-8 source file:

[image]

Comment: I can only guess at how your file is encoded, there's no way for me to check that. You'll need to find the appropriate conversion function for the way your source code file is encoded.

Comment: I couldn't know how my file is encoded, but it is in VS2008 default, and the OS is Win XP

Comment: I think the default for that is UTF-8, and the text on this web page is UTF-8 too. Did you try copy-pasting from this page into the editor?  There's also I believe an option when you do "save as...." to save with another encoding (which ends up telling you what the current encoding is because that's selected by default) on some of Microsoft's products.

Comment: Yes, when I went to "advanced save option" in VS2008, It gave me this line : "Arabic (Windows) - Codepage 1256"

Comment: Non-unicode, single-byte codepage (I think, really not a Windows expert). Try the other suggestion I edited. (I'm not sure I'll manage to reproduce what you have here.)

Comment: it is ok with "fromLocal8Bit"

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. That way the string literal itself will be Unicode for sure:

```
QString appTitle = QString::fromStdWString(L"تجربه");
```

Answer (score 0):

set a locale and use QString directly with arabic. In case you want to change the gui to english, you will have to change the locale and use tr in QString.

```
QString a=tr("تجربه")
```