# How Utf-8 may not work in Qt 5?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, utf-8, string-literals

I have a primitive test: the project in msvc2015 and Qt5.9.3.
The file `main.cpp` is saved in Unicode as UTF-8 with signature:

[image]

I try to show the message box which should show some text on Russian language. The whole code:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString ttl = QString::fromUtf8("russian_word_1");
    QString txt = QString::fromUtf8("russian_word_2");

    QMessageBox::information(nullptr, ttl, txt);

    return a.exec();
}
```

And what I receive:

[image]

How may this be possible?

---

**Update 1:** I want to use UTF-8 exactly with BOM [according to the Stackoverflow author's statement:](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

> *...It does not make sense to have a string without knowing what
>   encoding it uses*  ���

---

**Update 2:**
In this particular case, most likely it is a bug in the compiler.

Comment: Btw, be sure that you are compiling you application as unicode and/or your OS is configured to use Russian as default language for non-unicode programs.

Comment: I use VS2012, Qt 5.6, code saved as 'UTF-8 without BOM' and I can display german umlauts from code in QMessageBoxes: `QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Süß!"), tr("{ÄÊì&78╬aúeKã´YﭛᵴҺϸ̚Ƚ"));` - works out of the box.

Comment: @MartinHennings yes, but I talk about UTF-8 WITH Bom

Comment: Should make no difference. Qt5 interprets all string literals as UTF-8 (except if explicitly told not to do so), and I trust VisualStudio to encode the same, regardless of BOM. The real reason must lie somewhere else.

Comment: @MartinHennings , I have always worked `WITHOUT BOM`, and there were never problems. But today I decide to try `WITH` :)

Comment: It's not a bug. There is nothing in CPP standard about supporting non-ASCII (>127) characters in source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler produces garbage strings for UTF-8 source files that have a BOM, then it's a bug in the compiler. However, the use of a BOM with UTF-8 [is not recommended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark) in the first place. You shouldn't use it unless you actually have a reason to.

Furthermore, you don't need to do explicit `fromUtf8()` conversions. You can just do:

```
QString ttl = "russian_word_1";
QString txt = "russian_word_2";
```

`QString` assumes string literals are UTF-8. From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details):

> In all of the `QString` functions that take `const char *` parameters, the `const char *` is interpreted as a classic C-style `'\0'`-terminated string encoded in UTF-8.

You may use `QStringLiteral` to wrap string literals as an optimization, but this is not required.

Lastly, you can use `tr()` to wrap the string literals if you at some point want to translate the application from Russian to other languages. It is generally a good idea to use `tr()` in case you later decide to do a translation.

Note that having non-English strings in source code is generally fine. It's what UTF-8 (and Unicode in general) is there for. All modern compilers support it. What most people frown upon however, is non-English *code*:

```
auto индекс = 0; // Please don't.
```

But non-English *strings* are fine.

Comment: But what about this famous statement of the Stackoverflow author: The Single Most Important Fact About Encodings.. [**It does not make sense to have a string without knowing what encoding it uses**](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: @VladimirBershov In our case, we know what encoding it uses. It's UTF-8.

Comment: yes, but I'm talking about global correctness, and I want to use my project in another IDE too

Comment: @VladimirBershov Are there any modern IDEs that don't support UTF-8?

Comment: As we see, Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 at least

Comment: Now I am sure that it is absolutely wrong to save some text without an information of encoding

Comment: @VladimirBershov What do you mean with "information of encoding?"

Comment: @VladimirBershov Also, previously, you said " I have always worked WITHOUT BOM, and there were never problems. But today I decide to try WITH". So what is your problem exactly? You said it works fine without a BOM. And using a BOM with UTF-8 is NOT recommended to begin with.

Comment: Information on which every text editor can find out which encoding is used. Let's say I want to save text files in such a universal way to forget about encoding problems in general.

Comment: There were never problems while using msvc + Qt

Comment: @VladimirBershov A BOM is a **B**yte **O**rder **M**ark. It specifies byte order. Byte order is irrelevant for UTF-8 and using a BOM causes issues. Just like you don't need a BOM for ASCII files, you don't need one for UTF-8 either. Just use UTF-8 without a BOM and tell your IDE that your files are in UTF-8 instead of ASCII. That's the simplest solution.

Comment: There is special only for UTF-8 byte order mark, therefore it is a encoding flag too. The issues is caused by wrong applications, not by BOM

Comment: @VladimirBershov Well, you're free to ignore advice. I'm just telling you what the recommended approach is.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use non-english ASCII in your code. Because compilation depends on compiler, source file encoding etc. Write only english text, wrapped in [`tr("")`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-hellotr-example.html). Create translation files, load them. Read about [internalization in qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html).

[Another usefull link.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html)

Comment: Are you sure that this is the best solution for only-one language program?

Comment: @VladimirBershov yes, I think that is the only way. If you are using IDE-s like Visual Studio or QtCreator - then it should be easy to use.

Comment: @VladimirBershov It is good advice to use plain english strings and tr() them into your native language, but /in practice/ this should work, too. So no, this is not neccessarily the best solution for only-one language program - for multiple reasons (you need to lupdate / lrelease / distribute, harder to find strings seen in production, harder to convey exact meaning in non-native language etc.).

Comment: @DmitrySazonov , thanks, but I am sure that *Unicode* is the very thing for decide the problem once and forever. Every compiler should provide full support of Unicode (*especially* using BOM). Use only ASCII in code and use translation files are very good advices, but not for this reason.

Comment: @VladimirBershov you need to look for an answer, how to force MSVC to correctly interpret your source files. It is not related to Qt then.

Comment: @VladimirBershov, see this post anyway [Non English in source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436278/arabic-in-qt-with-qstring)

Comment: @VladimirBershov, I just wrote a different answer of the same problem, may be not your specific case, but generally without the cost of _internationalization_ these are the options we have for _Arabic_ text in source files.

Answer (score 1):

If your using Qt Creator + MSVC compiler, this may help you.

TLDR:

1. save all of your source files as UTF-8 **without** BOM
2. add this line in your .pro file:
   `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /utf-8`

Done!

refs:

1. [MSVC compiler flag to Set Source and Executable character sets to UTF-8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=vs-2019)
2. [Add compiler flag in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7982165/11158104)

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Visual Studio IDE. Yes, UTF-8-no-BOM is the best options for Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QByteArray` for your message text, then get it as unicode QString for display:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextCodec *codec1 = QTextCodec::codecForName("CP1256");
    // Converted Text:
    QByteArray myLanguage = "لا لا لا لا لا لا لا ";
    QString myLanguage2unicode = codec1->toUnicode(myLanguage);
    // Non converted text:
    QString txt = QString::fromUtf8("لا لا لا لا لا لا لا  ");

      QMessageBox::information(nullptr, myLanguage2unicode, txt);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Result of above code:

[image]

Comment: It depends on encoding of source files and compiler. Text codecs are not for that.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Usually, for simple, only-one language program, if find it costly to go for _internalization_ .. then, while writing _Non English_ text inside the source code, text `codecs` are a good solution .. I do use them.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, Just in case we are not on the same page, see my  code And snap shot of output, As I updated in my answer, the point here is its valid while it of course is not best choice for portable ...etc code.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, check this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436278/arabic-in-qt-with-qstring)

Comment: I believe that it is a very bad practice to rely on local PC encoding, because it may be changed at any moment. At least, source files should be in utf8/16/32.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov It is. but once your code is compiled, alas its utf8 string regardless of what you change _after_ that on local PC.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov This works for short to live, small applications .. while I spent a couple of weeks internationalizing a VS project to 4 languages .. hundreds of strings!

Comment: It is very cool, if you can do a correct translation on a 4 languages. But I'm sure that the time that you spent is nothing in compare with time, that you spent on coding.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, No! that was real internationalization with resource strings.